# Eigen c++ NaNs disappear when I try to print them

Tags: c++, nan, eigen, ofstream

I have written a code using Eigen in c++ which returns some NaNs and the whole thing blows up. When I try to print out variables (with ofstream) and trace back to where the NaN originated, suddenly the NaNs don't appear and the calculation completes successfully. Does anybody have any idea why this would happen? I don't think creating lots of random .txt files is a good fix!

Just in case it's relevant, the matrices I'm using are sparse (and large), and have been used earlier in the code and reset with .setZero() before the NaNs surface.

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour. Fix it.

Comment: See if you have uninitialized variables. If your code works and then fails the  next time you try it again, this is the thing to check.

Comment: @user3670482 It's taken me this long to find it, but you are absolutely spot on. One of my vectors was not initialising to zero when I thought it was. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for uninitialized variables.

Quite often, if your program works as per expectations and then fails the next time you try running it again for the same workflow, the cause is uninitialized variables. Of course, there are many other things that can cause this, but uninitialized variables are a very common cause for bugs like yours.